# Is it possible to use angular 2 with non-restapi backend?

Tags: java, servlets, angular

I'm currently building a project using angular 2 for front end.

Our backend is in core java (Servlet) and its not RESTful.

So, It it possible to use angular 2 with non-restapi backend?

Comment: What are those servlets returning, HTML pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't it?

Does your backend send `HTML`? `JSON`? `XML`? `Text`? Static files like JS, CSS, etc..

Chances are it does, at least one of them, so `Angular` can manipulate the response body anyway it wants - or any way you program it to.

It is the `HTTP request/response paradigm` that is important. Angular supports it, so it will handle non-RESTful backends (i.e response bodies).

Chances are you would need to probably modify your backend to send the proper data - either HTML snippets (JSP snippets gets translated to HTML in the end) or if you want JSON/XML strings,objects, whatever.

It is not impossible to do.